# Фильтрация словаря по значению в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, filter

У меня есть словарь, допустим:

```py
    result = [
              {
               'Stage_ID': 'S1',
               'Adress': 'Mexico', 
               'City': 'Mexico-City',
               'Сurrency': 'MXN'
              },
              {
               'Stage_ID': 'S2',
               'Adress': 'Netherlands', 
               'City': 'Harlem',
               'Сurrency': 'EUR'
              },
              {
               'Stage_ID': 'S1',
               'Adress': 'China', 
               'City': 'Beijing',
               'Сurrency': 'CNY'
              },
              {
               'Stage_ID': 'S3',
               'Adress': 'Panama', 
               'City': 'Penonome',
               'Сurrency': 'USD'
              }
             ]
```

Как мне в *Python* реализовать фильтрацию таким образом, чтобы на выходе получить всю информацию по ключу `Stage_ID` со значением `S1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [2]: res = [d for d in result if d["Stage_ID"] == 'S1']

In [3]: res
Out[3]:
[{'Stage_ID': 'S1',
  'Adress': 'Mexico',
  'City': 'Mexico-City',
  'Сurrency': 'MXN'},
 {'Stage_ID': 'S1', 'Adress': 'China', 'City': 'Beijing', 'Сurrency': 'CNY'}]

In [4]: res[0]
Out[4]:
{'Stage_ID': 'S1',
 'Adress': 'Mexico',
 'City': 'Mexico-City',
 'Сurrency': 'MXN'}

In [5]: res[1]
Out[5]: {'Stage_ID': 'S1', 'Adress': 'China', 'City': 'Beijing', 'Сurrency': 'CNY'}
```

Comment: Возможно с помощью этого способа реализовать для всех значений в словаре?

Comment: @Fox, можно. Привел пример в ответе